# How to get user object from request in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to get the password of curent user from request body and verify it.

I am trying to get user object from request like this:

```
class UserPasswordUpdateAsAdminViewSet(APIView):

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        serializer = ResetPasswordAsAdminSerializer(data=request.data,
                                                    context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.update_password()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={'success': True})
```

and below is my serializer:

```
class ResetPasswordAsAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    new_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate_password(self, attrs):
        self.user = None
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
            self.user = request.user

        if not self.user or not self.user.check_password(attrs['password']):
            raise CustomAPIException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                message='Invalid password provided',
                error_code=None
            )

    def validate_new_password(self, password):
        if not re.match(REGEX['password'], str(password)):
            raise CustomAPIException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT,
                message=None,
                error_code='password_policy_mismatch'
            )

        return password

    def update_password(self):
        self.user.set_password(self.validated_data['new_password'])
        self.user.save()
        return

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password', 'new_password')
```

But on hitting the api, I am getting the following error:

```
string indices must be integers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this in the serializer itself, it can be done in the views pretty easily take a look at this example

```
    serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        if not user.check_password(serializer.data.get('old_password')):
            return Response({'old_password': ['Wrong password.']}, 
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # set_password also hashes the password that the user will get
        user.set_password(serializer.data.get('new_password'))
        user.save()
        return Response({'status': 'password set'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return Response(serializer.errors,
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: That seems to be an easy solution, how can I use this user further in my serilaizer.
Can you explain? I am rather new to drf.

Comment: @AartiJoshi Well most of this stuff shouldn't be done in the serializer itself, you can do this in the views